# Imagemagick convert: Can't get -pointsize to use a calculated value for text annotation

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick for automated watermarking of arbitraty user images, using the 'convert' binary (6.9.1, Mac OS).

I've tried many things, including the following two approaches:

```
convert image.jpg -pointsize %[fx:w*0.05] -annotate 0 'Pointsize should be: %[fx:int(w*0.05)]' out.jpg
```

and

```
convert image.jpg -set value %[fx:w*0.05] -pointsize %[value] -annotate 0 'Pointsize should be: %[value]' out.jpg
```

in both cases the calculated value appears in the text label, but does not work in the pointsize setting.  I've confirmed that the pointsize option itself does work when setting a static value, e.g.

```
convert image.jpg -pointsize 30 -annotate 0 'Pointsize should be: 30' out.jpg
```

Am I completely off track here?  I'm not sure what else to try.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 4):

Mark Setchell has the best answer/solution. ImageMagick will not expand the variable artifacts passed to `-pointsize`, and will default to 1 *(you should see a very, very, small smudge that would be your text rendered @ 1pt.)*

**This is a hack**

Using the `+pointsize` option, or not even including any `-pointsize` argument, will invoke ImageMagick's `caption:` protocol to dynamically adjust point-size to fit the parent MBR (minimum bounding rectangle.)

Overload the `-size` argument by using `-set option:size` which will expand & respect the `%[fx:...]` variables.

```
convert wizard: -set 'option:size' '%[fx:w*0.5]x%[fx:h*0.5]' \
        +pointsize  caption:'This is dynamic pointsize' \
        -composite output.png
```

[image: dynamic point size]

**But you should really do what Mark suggest!**

Answer (score 1):

This works, but it is a bit kludgy and ugly as it uses the shell, and invokes a second process (ImageMagick's `identify`) and has to repeat the image name...

```
convert image.jpg                                               \
  -pointsize $(identify -format "%[fx:int(w*0.05)]" image.jpg)  \
  -gravity center -annotate 0 "Some Text" out.jpg
```

[image]

Still, it may get you going till I, or someone clever (@emcconville I am looking at you), works out how to do it properly :-)

**Note:**

I can see that I can set my own uniquely-named variable correctly to 5% of the width using this:

```
convert image.jpg -set option:phnqz '%[fx:int(w*0.05)]' -verbose info:

Image: image.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 200x200+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Type: Palette
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: sRGB
  Depth: 8/1-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 1-bit
    green: 1-bit
    blue: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 40000
    Red:
      min: 255 (1)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 255 (1)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
      entropy: nan
    Green:
      min: 255 (1)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 255 (1)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
      entropy: nan
    Blue:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 0 (0)
      mean: 0 (0)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
      entropy: nan
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 0 (0)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 170 (0.666667)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
      entropy: nan
  Colors: 1
  Histogram:
     40000: (255,255,  0) #FFFF00 yellow
  Rendering intent: Perceptual
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (0.64,0.33)
    green primary: (0.3,0.6)
    blue primary: (0.15,0.06)
    white point: (0.3127,0.329)
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: black
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 200x200+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: JPEG
  Quality: 92
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2015-08-04T17:14:55+01:00
    date:modify: 2015-08-04T17:14:55+01:00
    fx:int(w*0.05): 10
    jpeg:colorspace: 2
    jpeg:sampling-factor: 1x1,1x1,1x1
    signature: 0b798b7a624ba8417c5249dc58a50fa18c931dbde7fd60227bf932d5de228aba
  Artifacts:
    filename: image.jpg
    phnqz: 10                               <--- *** HERE IT IS ***
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 757B
  Number pixels: 40K
  Pixels per second: 0B
  User time: 0.000u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.000
  Version: ImageMagick 6.9.1-9 Q16 x86_64 2015-08-03 http://www.imagemagick.org
```